# Design and implement a class called Card that represents a standard playing card

Tags: java

Here is my issue, I have created this class which is incomplete because I am having issues on two levels. I might just be tired...so bear with me please.

1. I am having an issue trying to resolve having 5 random cards generate and not just 1 but more important no duplicates.
2. I am still fairly new to this but every time I try to add my main it says all my variables haven't been initialized. WTF...This is the biggest program/ first class I have had to write and I am just stuck.

help please

```
import java.util.*;

public class Card

    {
        private int suit;  // Initializes two variables for the card
        private int value;

public Card()  // constructor of the card that creates a random suit and value for the card

    {       
     Random num = new Random();
     suit = num.nextInt(4);
     value = num.nextInt(13)+1;
    }

        public Card(int Card_suit, int Card_value)  // constructor of the card that takes an int representing suit and value
            {
                suit = Card_suit;
                value = Card_value;
            }

            public int getValue()  // returns the numeric value of the card   

                {
                    return value;
                }

                public int getSuit()  // returns the numeric coded value of the card' suit

                    {
                        return suit;
                    }



   public String getSuitAsString()  // Return a String representing the card's suit.
                                    // (If the card's suit is invalid, "??" is returned.)
   {

    switch ( suit )
      {
        case 3: return "Spades";

        case 2: return "Hearts";

        case 1: return "Diamonds";

        case 0: return "Clubs";

        default: return "??";
      }

   }


        public String getValueAsString()  // Return a String representing the card's value.
                                          // If the card's value i// Compares the value of the card, to the value, as an int, of another card
                                          // returns true if value > other card, false if not invalid, "??" is returned.
        {
            switch ( value )
            {
                case 1: return "Ace";

                case 2: return "2";

                case 3: return "3";

                case 4: return "4";

                case 5: return "5";

                case 6: return "6";

                case 7: return "7";

                case 8: return "8";

                case 9: return "9";

                case 10: return "10";

                case 11: return "Jack";

                case 12: return "Queen";

                case 13: return "King";

                default: return "??";
            }

        }

        public String toString()  // overrides toString method,
        {
            return getValueAsString() + " of " + getSuitAsString(); // Return a String representation of this card, such as
                                                                    // "10 of Hearts" or "Queen of Spades".
        }


        public boolean compareValue(int cardOther)
        {

            return value > cardOther;

        }


            }
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your `main` method for us to see?

Comment: _"it says all my variables haven't been initialized"_ -- [Edit] your post to show us the ENTIRE program and also copy/paste in the error messages and/or stack trace so we can see which variables it thinks are uninitialized.

Comment: Honestly, this is all I have right now. I can't reference anything in the class or I am doing wrong and I am not sure how to proceed...starting with where I need to put my main(). Every time I try something new it I am doing this course on-line and don't really have a lot of support.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not create duplicate cards, you need to keep track of what cards are available. This makes me think of a Deck:

```
class Deck
{
    List<Card> cards;

    public Deck()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
            for (int value = 0; value < 13; value++)
                cards.add(new Card(suit, value);
    }

    public void shuffle()
    {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    public Card draw()
    {
        if (list.size() == 0)
        {
            // There's no cards left in the deck, you could
            // return null or throw an exception
            return null;
        }
        // Otherwise, take the last card out of the deck and return it
        return cards.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

In your main method, create a deck, shuffle it, and draw 5 cards.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    deck.shuffle();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Card card = deck.draw();
        System.out.println(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok here is my program linking my class, I am having an issue again, I still need it to not draw a duplicate cards which it does right now.

Comment: public class Dealer {

 Card Card = new Card();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  for (int k = 1; k <= 5; k++);
    {
          Card a = new Card();
       System.out.println (a);
       Card b = new Card();
       System.out.println (b);
       Card c = new Card();
       System.out.println (c);
       Card d = new Card();
       System.out.println (d);
       Card e = new Card();
       System.out.println (e);
    }
   
  }
  
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

IMO You have two options to get rid of problem-1:

1. Override `equals` method based on `suit_value` combo and every time you create an object of it put it in a `list` after checking if that already exist or not. If  it exists create a new one else keep it and put it in the list.
2. Similar as before but instead of `List` use a `Map` with key `suit+value -> respective Obj`.